# Vue-Loader not importing JS files using Webpack

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, vue-loader

I have the following in a folder...

```
 Test.vue
 Other.js
```

Here is the code...

```
Test.vue
<template>...</template>
<script>
    import Other from './other';
    ....
</script>

Other.js

export default class {
    constructor(){}
    static doSomething(){...}
}
```

But when I run and debug in the vue component ServerList is a ReferenceError...

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Other is not defined

For the record my Webpack config doesn't declare anything for JS but I didn't think I still needed babel...

```
module: {
    rules: [
        { test: /\.vue$/, loader: 'vue-loader' },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
        }
    ]
},
```

Not sure what I am missing, how would I make this work?

## UPDATE

If I configure babel for JS everything works, but I thought I could avoid babel at this point like I can with the entry point. Here is my webpack rule...

```
{
  test: /\.js$/,
  exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components|deps)/,
  use: {
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    options: {
      presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You mean you get that error specifically if you put a breakpoint and type `Other` into the console?

Comment: Correct with a breakpoint in the script for Test.

Comment: Have you found a solution?